# How can I convert my "myopenid" account into a (stackexchange) "openid" account?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm usually not a DAU in the computer-world... but it didn't appear to me how I could change my stackexchange-login, for which I'm using my "myopenid"-account, into a "stackexchange-openid" account; I want to avoid to create a new one (which needed a new user name) and then merge but rather keep my current username etc instead.

Could someone give practical advice here?

Comment: I think [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442/214632) MSO post might be helpful.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8185/what-happens-if-my-openid-provider-goes-out-of-business) help?

Comment: Upps, I forgot... Yes, I looked at it and got it managed, thank you. It is - for some reason possibly - much intransparent: I would have liked it more if explicitely the relation between the "userid","password","realname" from myopenid to something like "userid","password","displayed name","added login","email-adress" in SE were made more transparent; I felt much like without sight and had to do things without understanding. Well - it worked in the end very smooth, so this might be another anecdote in the expanding tale of the contemporary evolution of paradigms of software/user-interface...